# SFDX Prod Deployment attempting to run tests that have been deleted

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

I recently removed a trigger and an apex class from my Sandbox environment, along with the tests for these files. I am attempting to deploy to my production instance, but when I do the deployment tests fail attempting to run the tests for the classes that have been deleted.

- I removed the tests from my test suite in Production
- There is no reference of the trigger or class or its tests in my `project/main/default` folder

Why is it attempting to run tests for files and tests I've deleted?

Answer (score 1):

They're still being run because your trigger and tests still exist in production.

SFDX (and deployments in general) don't support specifying test suites to run (which is a shame). You're generally either going to be running *all local* tests in the org (i.e. running everything except tests for managed packages) or specifying an exhaustive list of tests that you want to run.

The SFDX team [has indicated that they will support destructive changes for force:source:deploy](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/188), but there hasn't been any communication about that in over a year, so...

It appears that you'll need to go through the metadata api (likely via ANT or force:mdapi:deploy) to delete your items in production.

[This related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311738/sfdx-will-sfdx-forcesourcedeploy-supports-destructive-changes-in-future) provides some alternatives (use unlocked packages or an NPM plugin by gdman)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the files from Sandbox or your Git project doesn't remove them from Production. You can't use a Change Set, either. You will need to use a "Destructive Changes" deployment to remove the code from production permanently. In DX, you might consider creating an Unlocked Package (that includes the files to delete), install it, then create a new version without the files (thus causing a delete) when you upgrade the package. You can read [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/332451/2984) of mine for more information.

Alternatively, if you just want to get it done, you might go straight to this Q&A that demonstrates how to use [destructiveChanges.xml and SFDX](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/343135/2984), which is pretty straight-forward if you already have SFDX available. Just create two manifest files, then deploy them with force:mdapi:deploy.

Third, you can use the "[No Software](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46617/2984)" solution that I outlined here, again with destructiveChanges.xml. It's an older post, but it gets the job done in just a few minutes with minimal effort. Really, it's kind of the same thing as the solution in the above paragraph, but uses the [Developer Workbench](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench) to get things done. There's a free, hosted version of the DW [here](https://workbench.developerforce.com/).

Comment: Such a complicated process for such a simple action